# SQL Server SSMS Bulk Insert Access denied

Tags: sql-server, ssms, bulkinsert

I'm trying to use the following codes to do some bulk insert:

```
BULK INSERT [xxx].[xxx].[xxx]
FROM 'E:\xxx\xxx.csv'
WITH (
  FIRSTROW = 2,
  FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
  ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
  TABLOCK
)
```

But it reports an error:

> Cannot bulk load because the file "E:\xxx\xxx.csv" could not be opened. Operating system error code (null).

Some posts show it's because my SSMS 2017 uses some sort of dummy account which doesn't have the permission to access the file on the shared drive.

I've tried running SSMS 2017 as admin, but it didn't work.

My question is how to create a domain account for SSMS 2017, so it can bulk insert? (a step-by-step guide is preferred).

Comment: How about giving full read access to the folder and the file to everyone? In addition: Maybe E: is a drive that is only mapped for your currently logged in user, not the user account that the SQL Server is running under?

Comment: Just to be sure - the file is located in that path on the server yes?

Comment: @ElementZero Yes, it is. Both the SQL DB and the "E:" drive are on Azure VM (windows)

Comment: When you log in using integrated authentication, SQL Server tries to impersonate that account to read the file. When you log in using SQL authentication, the engine uses its own credentials to access the file. (SSMS itself is mostly irrelevant in this discussion as it is not the one doing the bulk inserting in this case.) Which one are you using (and any chance you could try the other method)?

Comment: @JeroenMostert I can only log in using "SQL Server Authentication" wih login and password at the moment. This login is the admin of the database I'm looking at.

Comment: In that case, the account that the SQL Server service is running under must be able to access the file; the credentials you use to run SSMS are irrelevant. Recent installs of SQL Server will run as a virtual service account (`NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER`) with no permissions at all except the ones necessary for SQL Server to do its job. To read arbitrary files, permissions to read those files will have to be assigned to that account (or else you can run SQL Server under a different account, but this has its own security implications).

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks, how to check if that's the virtual service account? and how to assign permissions to that virtual account? I'm not familiar with SQL. If you could provide some links I can start doing some researches.

Comment: You can use the SQL Server Configuration Manager to check and change the account. This requires local access to the server. (You can read it remotely through `sys.dm_server_services`, but you can't change it this way.) Assigning permissions would be done how you usually assign permissions to files (using the permissions GUI from Explorer, or `icacls` from the command line, or `Set-Acl` from PowerShell, whatever's most appropriate). I'm pretty sure this can only be done with local access as well, as I don't think a virtual account will resolve remotely (but I've never tried this).